# Rollback operation for Laravel php artisan migrate:refresh --seed

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration

I am new to Laravel and I ran php artisan migrate:refresh --seed accidentally on a DB. How can I revert this operation?

Comment: you cant, you just reset and reran the migrations which dropped the tables and recreated them

Comment: ok, Thank you @lagbox. If you don't mind, can you please provide the details for those steps?

Comment: for what steps?

Comment: reset and migration steps I mean.

Comment: that is what `migrate:refresh` does, it reset all the migrations and reran them

Answer (score 1):

For your information, php artisan migrate:refresh recreates migration schema which you prepared in your laravel application. --seed can install data in newly created table/schema. There is no way to get data previously added database. If those data explicitly added manually in the database tables.